# do geometric fibers determine scheme-theoretic image?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X,Y,Z$ be reduced algebraic varieties, and let $Y$ and $Z$ be normal. Let $f:X \to Y$ and $g:X \to Z$ two surjective projective morphisms of algebraic varieties such that the geometric fibers of $f$ and $g$ coincide. Is there an isomorphism $h:Y\to Z$ such that $g=h \circ f$?

Comment: I don't understand "$Y$ and $Z$ coincide set-theoretically".

Comment: I mean that there's a one-to-one map between the set of closed points of $Y$ and the set of closed points of $Z$.

Comment: I don't understand, $f$ and $g$ have different targets, so how can they be the same morphism unless $Y=Z$? Do you mean that $Y$ and $Z$ have the same underlying topological space? In that case the answer is still no: Let $Y$ be a non-reduced scheme, $X=Z=Y_{red}$, $f:Y_{red}\to Y$ the inclustion and $g$ the identity.

Comment: In fact I mean exactly that (I did some editing adding an irreducibility hypothesis, thank you!): are the hypothesis enough to assure that $Y=Z$ and the morphism is the same. I mean that $Y$ and $Z$ have the same underlying set, no topology.

Comment: You can consider the normalisation morphism $f:\mathbb{P}^1 \to Y$ of a rational curve with one cuspidal singularity and the identity map of $\mathbb{P}^1$. Both morphisms are set-theoretically bijections but they do not conincide. So you need to add some sort of (semi-)normality hypothesis to get a statement which has some chance of being true.

Comment: I still don't understand. Any positive-dimensional complex algebraic variety $Y$ has the same cardinality as, say, $[0,1]$. Fixing a bijection, we obtain by transport of structure a complex variety $Y'$ isomorphic to $Y$, with underlying set $[0,1]$. 

Now, starting with $f$ and $g$ but without your assumption on $Y$ and $Z$, we can apply the above construction and get, by composition, $f':X\to Y'$ and $g':X\to Z'$ where $Y'$ and $Z'$ have the same underlying set. In other words, this assumption on $Y$ and $Z$ is not a restriction.
 

Comment: @ulrich: that's a good counterexample, thank you. I guess I have to assume $Y$ and $Z$ normal (or maybe just one of them) In that case I believe that the statement should be true.

@Laurent: yes, you are right, thank you. basically that (very weak) assumption descends from the other hypothesis. I will edit the question.

Comment: In response to J.C. Ottem's comment, you inserted the word "irreducible", but you meant (or should have meant) to insert the word "reduced".

Comment: @ steven: yes, of course!

Comment: Let $f$ and $g$ be constant maps to two non-isomorphic varieties.

Comment: I think you want the maps to be surjective.  Also, I suggest you rephrase the question to ask whether there exists an isomorphism $h: Y \to Z$ such that $g = h \circ f$.

Comment: I agree with S. Carnahan ... change "projective" to "surjective". I also propose changing the title to something like "Do geometric fibers determine scheme-theoretic image?" This is shaping up to be a very interesting question! +1.

Comment: @Anton. While surjective needs to be added, the statement becomes false if you just remove "projective". Consider $X = Y = \mathbf A^1 \cup \{\mathrm{pt}\}$ and $Z = \mathbf P^1$ with $f = \id$, $g$ the obvious map...

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the statement has been edited and now it looks much better!


Answer (score 11, accepted):

In positive characteristic, you get a counterexample by taking $X=Y=Z=$ the affine line (say), $f$ the identity and $g$ the Frobenius map.

Assume now that the ground field is algebraically closed of characteristic zero. Consider the map $(f,g):X\to Y\times Z$. Its image $\Gamma$ is a closed subvariety of $Y\times Z$. The assumption on the fibers exactly means that both projections from $\Gamma$ to $Y$ and $Z$ are bijective (on closed points). Since they are proper they must be (in char. zero) finite birational, hence (by normality) isomorphisms. So, $\Gamma$ is the graph of the isomorphism we are looking for.

Comment: Wonderful argument! The confusing part for me is why proper bijective implies finite birational in characteristic zero. I see that proper and quasi-finite implies finite. Because of characteristic zero, we have that the map is smooth on an open upstairs (right?), so it is smooth on an open set of the base (finite bijection implies homeomorphism?). Now there is an open set in the base where the map is finite, smooth (so etale), with connected fibers, so is an isomorphism. Is this the right approach?

Comment: @Anton: yes, that's also how I see it.